# sagetex.sty not found

Tags: installing, sagetex

I have ubuntu 15.10 and sage 6.9 installed, and texlive/texmaker, and have been trying to get sagetex to work.

I followed the instructions in the reference manual, and first attempted the 3rd, and stated most advisable method of making sagetex.sty known to tex. And as advised I copied the sagtex.sty file into my home texmf directory, by way of , with appropriate substitutions.

When I tried to compile my tex document, the following error message was displayed in texmaker:

[image: screenshot from texmaker]

Not understanding why this did not work, I went back and attempted the second suggestion by defining the environmental variable , again with relevant substitutions, and again with same resulting error code in texmaker.

Now I watched a video where Dan Drake was giving a presentation in which after he ran tex over the document, then ran a command like  and then sage ran on the document and when he reran tex the document was produced with appropriate evaluations by sage.
So in short I don't know what I don't know. Did I not properly make tex aware of which directory the sagetex.sty file is located in? Or am I not using sage correctly or something?

We don't use sage in school so I have no assistance in the matter, if I am making an obvious mistake, perhaps one could imagine why.

**UPDATE**

The following is the error message from sagetex;

!latex error: file 'sagetex.sty' not found. type x to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (default extension:sty) enter file name:!emergency stop. ^^M

Also, there are no example.sagetex.sage file, or example.sagetex.sout files being produced.

Comment: Please copy the text of the error message for better readability and searchability.

Comment: (off-topic) I download Sage 6.10.beta1 and turns out there are some bugs in `sage.py`. Perhaps you might want to test them in your working directory prior to any nontrivial installation.

Comment: @Null I have updated my question to include the error

Comment: @user74091 Could you include a link to the video you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Placing file to TeX directory (local or main) is not enough for TeX system to find it. TeXLive makes a list of files (not directories) which it can use, so you must first refresh database by `texhash` command, if TeX directory needs `superuser` permissions, then `sudo texhash`, because it makes changes in the directory, overwriting list of files.